# Can a submit button work without refresh AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a problem with my very simple chat. The page is constanly refreshing with AJAX with an timeout of 750ms. If I press or use enter to submit my 'reaction', the page refreshes: is there an way to remove that, so that you can instantly see what you've posted?

You can see the chat at my website: [chat](http://chaotix.nl/chat/)

The code: 
Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php include 'config.php'; ?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js">
function submitenter(myfield,e)
{
var keycode;
if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
else if (e) keycode = e.which;
else return true;

if (keycode == 13)
   {
   myfield.form.submit();
   return false;
   }
else
   return true;
}


</script>

    <title>JavaScript Chat</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="chatwindow">

        </div>

        <div class="inputMessage">
            <form method="post">


    enter code here

            <hr></hr>
                <textarea name="message" rows="1" cols="55"></textarea><br/>Fill username here<br/>
                <input type="text" value="" name="username" />
                <input type="submit" value="verstuur" name="submit" onKeyPress="return submitenter(this,event)" />

            </form>
            <?php   include 'send.php'; ?>      
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval ( "get()", 750 );
          });
          function get(){
             $.ajax({
               type: 'GET',
               url: 'chat.php',
               success: function(data){
                 $("#chatwindow").html(data);
               }
             });
          }
        </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

chat.php

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';
    $result = mysql_query("select * from Message");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<p>' . $row['username'] . " : " . $row['message'] . '</p>';
    }
?>
```

send.php

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
    if (!empty($_POST['username']))
        {
            if(!empty($_POST['message']))
            {
                $message =  mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['message']));
                $username =  mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['username']));
                $query = "INSERT INTO Message (`username`,`message`) VALUES ('".$username."','".$message."')";
                mysql_query($query);
            }
            else
            {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(\'Je kan niet niks sturen\')</script>'; 
            }
        }
    else
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(\'Vul een gebruikresnaam in!\')</script>';
    }
}
?>
```

if my question is not clear say it please.
And is there a topic/question/post about good spacing? google translated it as "indent".
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
<form method="post">
```

With

```
 <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault()" method="post">
```

You may also use your callback function here like:

```
 <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();return submitenter(this,event);" method="post">
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/5RCwF/2/

Comment: Thank you, but if I change my <form....> to youre answer, it totally stop working. Should I add some js?

Comment: Do what you want to do in callcack function `<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();return yourCallbackFunction();" method="post">`

Comment: I got in firebug the error : submitenter is not defined , after youre edit.

Comment: Just an example. I think you have to learn JS basics to complete this yourself. You even don't have your `<script>` tag correct.

Comment: Thank you, I think that is my problem to. Maybe I am going to fast, do you know a good website ? or shall I go for the basics to w3schools?

Answer (score 1):

Add `e.preventDefault();` in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired action is to prevent the onSubmit action as the other answers have mentioned.  Currently your script isn't quite ready to block submit as you don't have an ajax post method.

You need ajax functionality for the submission side of the application still.  For this you can use [jQuery post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

You want to create something like

```
function send() {
    $.post(); // Fill in appropriate post() code.
    return false;
}
```

And then call it from your event handlers like `onsubmit="return send()"` and in place of `myfield.form.submit()` in your keypress handler.

Comment: Thank you, I will look later to this!